# DataTables: get textContent of cell before the selected cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I can get the selected cell textContent like this:

`this.textContent`

but I want to get the textContent of cell before the selected cell. How can I do that?. I tried like this but it says `undefined`:

```
$('#dtBasicExample').on('click', 'tbody td', function() {

  var table = $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();


  var colIndex = table.cell(this).index().column-1;//get previous column index
  var rowIndex = table.cell(this).index().row;//get row index

  var Text=table.cells(rowIndex, colIndex).textContent;//get textContent(not working)

    alert(Text);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `table.cell(rowIndex, colIndex).data()` instead of `table.cells(rowIndex, colIndex).textContent;`

```
var table = $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();

$('#dtBasicExample').on('click', 'tbody td', function () {

    var colIndex = table.cell(this).index().column - 1; //get previous column index
    var rowIndex = table.cell(this).index().row; //get row index

    // Use data() instead of textContent and cell instead of cells
    var text = table.cell(rowIndex, colIndex).data(); 

    alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Datatable check `_DT_CellIndex` attribute inside Jquery object of triggered element to determine column and row.

> We can simply modify _DT_CellIndex before load it with Datatable

Sample code:

```js
$('#example').on('click', 'td', function() {
  var table = $(this).closest('table').DataTable();
  $(this)[0]._DT_CellIndex.column-=1;
  alert(table.cell($(this)).data());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Numero</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>155555</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```